# ReactJS jsx load img URI from a string (doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to load an image URI from props and not having any luck. I can of course load the image with:

```
import logoURI from '../assets/image.png';
<...>
<img src={logoURI} />
```

but I need to get away from the static URI and load it from props.

This works:

```
<div className="logo">
  <img
    src={require("../assets/image.png")}
  />
</div>
```

But this does not (`Cannot find module '../assets/image.png'`):

```
var logoURI = "../assets/image.png";
return (
  <div className="logo">
    <img
      src={require(logoURI)}
    />
  </div>
)
```

A string is a string? How do I make this work? In my terminal I see:

`Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

Comment: @ZohirSalak slam dunk - nice, simple solution. It changes my design a bit but I can live with it! Repost as an answer and I will check it.

Comment: Oops - the comment seems to have been deleted. The solution (a solution) as to move the `assets` folder under `public` and then there's no need to `import` or `require` the URI.

Comment: i deleted it, as the issue seem to be weird id like to know how to solve it, i'm guessing it's like the import keyword where you not allowed to supply the path as a variable probably just a `nodejs` thingy

Comment: Yes all my searching for that warning led me to "backleveling webpack" and other less than optimal solutions. Moving it all into /public at least allows me to assign the asset names from redux state, even if it does force the location. It works - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending your `logoURI` with `./`:

```
var logoURI = "./../assets/image.png";
```

## EDIT

If you need to `require` anything like that, you need to install `request`:

```
npm install request -g
```

Comment: No luck. Same error in the browser and in the terminal.

Comment: Edited @Omortis, any better?

Comment: Hmm I don't think so. At run-time this it is a static, local file location. I am trying to resolve a build time dependency.